# How to put a constraint on two combined fields?

Tags: sql, db2

I'd like to put a constraint, a check or a foreign key, on two combined fields from table1 to another field in table2. Here is what I tried, but both gave me errors:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
    ADD CONSTRAINT foo CHECK (field1 || field2 IN (SELECT fieldx FROM table2));

ALTER TABLE table1
    ADD CONSTRAINT foo FOREIGN KEY (field1 || field2) REFERENCES table2 (fieldx);
```

Is this possible? If yes, how? Beside this, is it generally possible to use subselects in CHECK Constraints?

I'm using DB2/LINUX 9.5.0.

**Solution:**
It seems to be only possible with an extra column, that holds the combinied value. The good thing is, [Tony Andrews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18747/tony-andrews) pointed out, there is a way to create expression generated columns in DB2.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    field1 CHARACTER(5),
    field2 CHARACTER(5),
    fieldx CHARACTER(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (field1) || field2),
    CONSTRAINT FK_X FOREIGN KEY (fieldx) REFERENCES table2 (fieldx)
```

);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to hold a computed column on table1 i.e.

```
fieldx = (field1 || field2)
```

I don't know if DB2 supports computed (aka virtual) columns as such, but if not you can create a regular column and maintain it via a trigger.  The create the foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
    ADD CONSTRAINT foo FOREIGN KEY (fieldx) REFERENCES table2 (fieldx);
```

Another possibility, of course, would be to modify your table design so that the keys are held consistently: if field1 and field2 are atomic values, then they should appear as such in table2, not as a concatenated value (which more or less breaks 1NF).

Comment: Yes, that works. The "computed column" pointer lead me to this: http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/183293-computed-columns-db2. In DB2 they seem to be called "expression generated" columns. I'll update my question with this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't, the foreign key must have the same number of columns as the parent key, also consider that keys need indexes, so consider them as "look-up".

For one FK to one PK:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (fk1)
     REFERENCES table2 (key1) ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

If a key on table 2 is composite (key1, key2)

```
ALTER TABLE table1
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (fk1,fk2)
     REFERENCES table2 (key1,key2) ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

Comment: So, you say it isn't possible?

Comment: Not the way you are trying to do. You could create a separate field with your calculated result and use that as a key.

Comment: I see. Actually, that the same Tony says, but he also pointed me to computed columns, so I accepted his answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 3 constraints: 2 nullable foreign keys for field1 and field2, and a constraint that only one of two is not null.

Of course, you can relax the constraints and omit the last one.

Comment: I don't get it. Could you describe your answer in more detail please? Why should I check something against null?

Comment: I just got you wrong, sorry. Somewhy I thought || is not a concatenation, but an "or".
BTW, is it a concatenation, or it's rather a compound key? If latter, it makes me think table2.fieldx is not atomic, and thus is not in 1NF.